# How to know the number of goats given birth by a particular she goat

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how many children a particular she goat has given birth to. Below is my code which is not giving me what i want so somebody should help me out, please.

```
<?php

include("db.php");



$query = "SELECT mothername, COUNT(goatid) FROM goats GROUP BY     mothername"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(goatid)'] ." ". $row['mothername'] ."   Children Goat(s).";
echo "<br/>";
}


?>
```

Comment: "not giving me what I want" is a useless description (kind of like telling the doctor "I am sick, but it's not what I thought it was, so what is it?"). What is it that it is giving you?

Comment: I want the script to be able to display/show the number of goats (children) given birth by a particular goatid (mothername). i.e. goatid column contains names of all goats (both male and female) while mothername column contains the names of mother goats all from goats table

Comment: is the query working? have you checked for errors? blah blah basics you do before asking

Comment: That's what you *want*. That was evident. You did not answer my question - what is it giving you? I don't have your database, I don't particularly feel like mocking one up on my computer just to test your code, and it takes more effort than it's worth to execute your code in my wetware, when you can simply tell us whether there is an error message (and which), or whether you are getting wrong results (and which), if you're getting no results at all, if your computer is catching fire, or if FBI is emailing you that you are not authorised for the goat access.

Comment: Here is the result I am getting; "There are 5 Children Goat(s).
There are 1 SG0002 Children Goat(s)." Which I want it to show " There are 5 Children Goat(s). SG0002 has 1 Children Goat(s)

Comment: So in `There are 5 Children Goat(s)` there is no mother name, right? In the second example `SG0002` is the mother name, is that correct? If so just rewrite the sentence to the format you want.

Comment: @IgbehEmmanuel, you have had ample time to clarify your question.  I am flagging it for closure.  You need to supply your metadata, sample data, the result you expect and the result you are getting !!!

Comment: @chris85, SG0002 is the mother name. The format I want is "There are 5 Children Goat(s),  SG0002 has 1 Child" and if another mother name is say SG0003 then it should be able to list them as There are 5 Children Goat(s), SG0002 has 1 child, SG0003 has 2 Children and so on.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The 5 children goat would be from the same mother name, not `SG002` and `SG003`. You are grouping by the mother name so you are going to just get counts of the # of children each mother has.

Comment: @chris85, Some goats were bought from market some we dont know there mother's name so it does not necessary mean every every number child goat must have a mother but only those given birth that would have mother name listed under them

Comment: All the unnamed ones are going to be grouped as one count.

Comment: @chris85, please how? example for instance

Comment: You say group by mothername so all mothernames that are `NULL` are the same and count +1 for each row. Then  `SG002` is counted +1 for each row.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally gotten the logic. here is it

```
include("db.php");



$query = "SELECT mothername, COUNT(goatid) FROM goats GROUP BY mothername"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo  $row['mothername'] ." has ". $row['COUNT(goatid)'] ." Kid(s).";
echo "<br/>";
}


?>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions which has really help me. Chris, Amadan, Dagon and others

Comment: Looks like the same code with just a different sentence, no? You should indent your control blocks (`if`, `while`, `switch`, `function`, etc.) so it is easier to read.